# Google play services not accepted

Tags: android, google-play-services

ihave installed the lastest version
still i am getting the issue like this 
initially when i add the library:

[image]

and after i apply and go back to properties i get the red cross:

[image]

i dont know what to do?
please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your library from SDK path like this "D:\android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin".

Comment: i am importing from the same path. i tried unstalling it from sdk manager. then i reinstaled it and used it. and the funny part is that it is working for other projects